# Is there a way to have lazy pickers similar to a lazyvstack?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Currently, I have a popup menu that contains two wheel pickers. I have create a drag gesture to allow swiping the popup menu away. However, as I add more entries to the picker wheels, the drag gesture becomes more and more laggy. The animation is fluid if I remove one of the pickers, or if I have less entries. How can I keep the animation fluid while having a lot of entries in both pickers? I have tried using a drawingGroup, however it doesn't work with a picker. Is there something along the lines of lazy loading for pickers?

Here are the pickers on the popup:

```
GeometryReader { geo in
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Picker(selection: $selection1) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< array1.count) { index in
                        ...
                    }
                } label: {
                }
                .labelsHidden()
                .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                .frame(width: geo.size.width / 2)
                .compositingGroup()
                .clipped()

                Picker(selection: $selection2) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< array2.count) { index in
                        ...
                    }
                } label: {
                }
                .labelsHidden()
                .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                .frame(width: geo.size.width / 2)
                .compositingGroup()
                .clipped()
            }
        }
```

Here is the popup menu containing the pickers:

```
VStack {
                    ZStack {
                        ZStack {
                            Color("whiteblack")
                            VStack {
                                Capsule()
                                    .frame(width: 40, height: 5)
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                    .padding(.top, 5)
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        }
                        .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)
                            .onChanged({ value in
                                let amt = prevDragHeight - value.translation.height
                                if slideOffset >= 0 {
                                    slideOffset -= amt
                                }
                                if slideOffset < 0 {
                                    slideOffset = 0
                                }
                                prevDragHeight = value.translation.height
                            })
                            .onEnded({ _ in
                                if slideOffset > 70 {
                                    withAnimation(.interactiveSpring()) {
                                        slideOffset = 0
                                        isShowing = false
                                    }
                                    slideOffset = 0
                                } else {
                                    withAnimation(.interactiveSpring()) {
                                        slideOffset = 0
                                    }
                                }
                                prevDragHeight = 0
                            })
                        )
                        DoublePicker()
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: 400)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(.white)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .padding()
                .padding(.bottom)
                .offset(x: 0, y: slideOffset)
                .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
```

Comment: use `.compositingGroup()` on the VStack of the popup.

Comment: @ChrisR it still seems to be lagging when I build it on my iPhone Xs. When I run it in the simulator, the app runs perfectly fine

Comment: Fixed the issue by just creating a multipicker in UIKit instead of using SwiftUI's Pickers